# Creating child elements via Props in React.createElement

Tags: reactjs

I am an angular developer and I have just started exploring the react API using https://babeljs.io/repl.

I have just added the CDN script tags for react in HTML and started to explore the `React.createElement` API.

```
// jsx
var e2 = <div>hello</div>;

// babel generated script
var e2 = React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    "hello"
);
ReactDOM.render(e2, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have copied babel generated .js to html and it worked. Later I started to explore `props`.

```
// jsx
const e5 = <div name="taylor">{this.props.name}</div>;

// babel generated script
const e5 = React.createElement(
    "div",
    { name: "taylor" },
    this.props.name// This throws undefined
);
ReactDOM.render(e2, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am sure `this` refers to the window object and since props are undefined, throws an error. So what exactly does it generate? or Am I missing something else (closure or context)?

Just curious to know what is the js code to put to make it work?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it throws an error since props don't have `age` value. It has only `name` in it

Comment: @Thinker updated still the same error. basically when property does not exist it will return undefined and not error, if props itself undefined then throws error. :). Technically the problem is not because of age or name it's because `this.props` is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React has **2 ways** to create component, that is use `Function` or `Class` Components, you can refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

`this` is only work with `Class` Component way to get `props`, with `Function` way, we should pass `props` as parameter.

This is my demo how to create element by function on **jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/e9sjzndL/

### Function Component way

You can do like with JSX

```
const E5 = (props) => <div>{props.name}</div> // create a component

const e5 = E5({name: 'taylor'})               // create an element

ReactDOM.render(e5, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And Babel will generate to

```
const E5 = props => React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  props.name
);
const e5 = E5({ name: 'taylor' });

ReactDOM.render(e5, document.getElementById('root'));
```

### Class Component way

You can do like with JSX

```
class E6 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
    }
}

const e6 = <E6 name="taylor"/>

ReactDOM.render(
  e6,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And Babel will generate to

```
class E6 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      this.props.name
    );
  }
}

const e6 = React.createElement(E6, { name: "taylor" });

ReactDOM.render(e6, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks ! Note if you use the `Function Component way` in a map, you need to pass the `key` to the subcomponent like this : `const E5 = (props) => <div key={props.key}>{props.name}</div> // create a component` and `const e5 = E5({name: 'taylor', key: 'taylor'}) `

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is that the `createElement` has three parameters.

1. The type of the element that you want to create (like `div`, `span`, `h1`) or the react component.
2. The second argument is the properties that you will be passing to the element.

   a) Here, if the element is a React component, then the properties will be passed to the component and can be accessed by the `this.props` as you did in your code.

   b) If it is an HTML element, then it will be assigned it to the element itself. Example: class name, id name, CSS style
3. The last argument is the children of that component. This can be a quoted string like shown in your code, in which case the content will be interpreted as text.

Therefore, your code will be working if you do like this:

```js
var props = { name: "taylor" }

const e5 = React.createElement(
    "div",
    { className: "taylor", id: "asd", style: {color: 'red'} },
    'hello'+props.name
);
```

If you want to create a react component, then do something like:

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});
var props = { name: "taylor" }

const es5component = React.createElement(Hello, props)

ReactDOM.render(es5component, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLVgpa?editors=1010)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not referring to anything if you think of `<div name="taylor">{this.props.name}</div>;` as plain JSX (even it is undefined if you try to transpile it on https://es6console.com/).

Actually `this` does not refer to inner scope of `React.createElement`. It refers to the value of `this` where you are executing `<div name="taylor">{this.props.name}</div>;`.

For example, if you are writing same JSX in a class based component's render function, `this` will refer to that component. And if it has `name` in its props, it will be passed down as param to `createElement`. This example elaborates more.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class MyComp extends Component {

    render () {
        // you have access to 'SomeName' in 'div' props not 'MyComp' props. but you are not defining div. right?
        return (<div name="SomeName">{this.props.name}</div>)
    }
}

class SomeOther extends Component {
    render () {
        // "TopLevelName" is available in MyComp as prop.
        return (<MyComp name="TopLevelName" />)
    }
}
```